# Javascript drop-down form math calculation

Tags: javascript, html, menu, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a page where there are two dropdown menus, and then when the user presses submit, it calculates a price based on the data given from the dropdown menu. It needs to take either 1 or 2 from the first dropdown menu choice, multiply that by the value of the second dropdown menu choice, multiply that by 0.2, and output it when the user presses submit. I've tried to make it work but I keep getting NaN errors. Any help?

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function price() {
        var sqBn = document.priceCalc.squareOrBanner;
        var Amt = document.priceCalc.number;
    var price = sqBn * Amt * 0.2;
    document.write(price);
}
</script>

<form name="priceCalc" action="priceCalcPage.html" onsubmit="document.write(price())">
<div align="center">
<select name="squareOrBanner">
<option value="1">Square</option>
<option value="2">Banner</option>
</select>

<select name="number">
<option value="250">250</option>
<option value="500">500</option>
<option value="750">750</option>
<option value="1000">1000</option>
</select>
<br><input type="submit" value="Figure out pricing!"><br>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't know much about low-level DOM, but are you sure document.priceCalc.squareOrBanner is actually available?  Stick some `alert()` traces in there to see what sqBn and Amt are set to.

Comment: Sorry but I've written hardly any JS in the past few years, I have no idea how to even troubleshoot this, but it should be a simple fix, since the code seems to work correctly as pseudocode at least.

Comment: I would suggest giving the different menus ids so you can do `document.getElementById('number').value` which would return the value for the number menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/JSvSn/1/

You need to access the `value` property in those objects:

```
var price = sqBn.value * Amt.value * 0.2;
```

*EDIT:* Here's a version that updates the value of an input box with the price: http://jsfiddle.net/JSvSn/5/

*EDIT 2:* [Show price in a div.](http://jsfiddle.net/JSvSn/7/)

Comment: Thank you, that worked. How do I make the value appear without the page refreshing? Like adding it below the form rather than it being the only thing when the button is pressed?

Comment: you can use onchange or onselect event of the select list to run your calculation.

Comment: onchange works halfway the way I want it, but it still keeps refreshing the page to show the value returned rather than outputting it after the form.

Comment: @bluesmoon It does when you have a value for each option element. I tested it on Safari, Chrome and FF. Can't do IE though, I am on OS X

Comment: @Aircule Thanks so much, that's almost perfect. Just one last thing, is there a way I could output the number without it being in an input box like that? Like just as a plain number as far as the user is concerned?

Comment: @bluesmoon Honestly I have no clue. I had IE6 installed at some point, but it's gone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the `sqBn.value` will work on all browsers. It would be safer to use

```
sqBn.options[sqBn.selectedIndex].value
```

and if you are still getting NaN results then try

```
parseInt(sqBn.options[sqBn.selectedIndex].value)
```

If you want to do this calculation without refreshing the page change the form declaration like this:

```
<form name="priceCalc" action="priceCalcPage.html" onsubmit="document.write(price());return false;">
```

In this way the onsubmit will be executed, but won't submit anything to the action. If you want to submit it, you can still do it from javascript (`document.priceCalc.submit()`).