# calculation using dropdown box and textbox

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, dropdownbox

Before you guys shoot me down for not trying the code, I am very new to Javascript and I need to implement this function into a very important work.

I got the basis dropdown calculation from this thread, [Javascript drop-down form math calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278214/javascript-drop-down-form-math-calculation). I modified the code referred from the thread for my codes

Forgive me if my codes is totally wrong, I am still trying to do piece by piece. Will be grateful if you all can help me pinpoint the errors and/or issues.

So back to topic, I want to get the cost for each items, and then count the total cost to be calculated. The JSFiddle link is    [here](http://jsfiddle.net/chrislee/gd12k4mt/). Appreciate for your helps rendered.

HTML CODES

```
<form name="priceCalc" action="">Laundry (Gentlemen)
<br/>Apparels:
<select name="gapparell" onchange="gentlemanl();">
    <option value="5.00">Tie</option>
    <option value="7.50">Shirt</option>
    <option value="12.50">Jacket</option>
</select>
<br>Quantity:
<input type="text" id="gqtyl" onchange="gentlemanl();" />
<br>
<br/>Dry Cleaning (Gentlemen)
<br/>Apparels:
<select name="gappareld" onchange="gentlemand();">
    <option value="6.00">Tie</option>
    <option value="8.50">Shirt</option>
    <option value="13.50">Jacket</option>
</select>
<br>Quantity:
<input type="text" id="gqtyd" onchange="gentlemand();" />
    <br/><br/><br/>Laundry (Ladies)
<br/>Apparels:
<select name="lapparell" onchange="ladiesl();">
    <option value="5.00">Tie</option>
    <option value="7.50">Shirt</option>
    <option value="12.50">Jacket</option>
</select>
<br>Quantity:
<input type="text" id="lqtyl" onchange="ladiesl();" />
<br>
<br/>Dry Cleaning (Ladies)
<br/>Apparels:
<select name="lappareld" onchange="ladiesd();">
    <option value="6.00">Tie</option>
    <option value="8.50">Shirt</option>
    <option value="13.50">Jacket</option>
</select>
<br>Quantity:
<input type="text" id="lqtyd" onchange="ladiesd();" />
<br>Total Cost:
<input type="text" id="prices">
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Figure out pricing!" onclick="total();">
<br>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODES

```
function gentlemanl() {
var Amt = document.priceCalc.gapparell;
var Qty = document.priceCalc.gqtyl;
var price = parseInt(Qty.value) * parseFloat(Amt.value);
document.getElementById("prices").value = price; 
}

function gentlemand() {
var Amt = document.priceCalc.gappareld;
var Qty = document.priceCalc.gqtyd;
var price = parseInt(Qty.value) * parseFloat(Amt.value);
document.getElementById("prices").value = price;
}

function ladiesl() {
var Amt = document.priceCalc.lapparell;
var Qty = document.priceCalc.lqtyl;
var price = parseInt(Qty.value) * parseFloat(Amt.value);
document.getElementById("prices").value = price;
}

function ladiesd() {
var Amt = document.priceCalc.lappareld;
var Qty = document.priceCalc.lqtyd;
var price = parseInt(Qty.value) * parseFloat(Amt.value);
document.getElementById("prices").value = price;
}

function total() {
//I am not sure how the function works
}
```

Comment: You have typos, `gentlemanl` and `ladiesl`, not `gentleman1` and `ladies1`.

Comment: @fuyushimoya okay, I saw this. But is the code really correct in a sense? because it is still not working

Comment: You have to switch `Frameworks & Exts`'s `onload` to `no wrap - in XXX`, see the [altered jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gd12k4mt/6/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a working exemple of what i think you want to do : http://jsfiddle.net/gd12k4mt/5/

```
function gentleman1() {
    var Amt = document.priceCalc.gapparell;
    var Qty = document.priceCalc.gqtyl;
    return parseInt(Qty.value) * parseFloat(Amt.value);
}
```

I designed the functions like that. With a return statement for the value of each product * the quantity.

```
function total() {
if(isNaN(gentleman1())) {
    gentleman_laundry = 0;
} else {
    gentleman_laundry = gentleman1();
}

if(isNaN(gentlemand())) {
     gentleman_dry = 0;   
} else {
     gentleman_dry = gentlemand();
}

if(isNaN(ladies1())) {
   ladies_laundry = 0;   
} else {
   ladies_laundry = ladies1();
}

if(isNaN(ladiesd())){
   ladies_dry = 0;   
} else {
   ladies_dry = ladiesd();
}

var totalPrice = gentleman_laundry+gentleman_dry+ladies_laundry+ladies_dry;

document.getElementById('prices').value = totalPrice;
}
```

The total function is like that with a test on empty fields. In this purpose I created the variables :

```
var gentleman_laundry,
    gentlemend_dry,
    ladies_laundry,
    ladies_dry;
```

Be sure that your functions's name is good : here you have two different names in you're html events and in your script.

I personally did without theses html listeners because we want the total price at the end I guess. So I declared only one listener on the final button.

```
document.getElementById('submit_button').addEventListener('click', function(){
    total();
})
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: @Mteuahasn, it works! But i have some question to ask. Is it possible to implement into Wordpress and also have the email feature? For now, I just need the calculation feature but I may be asked to input all the selected field and total cost in an email to send

Comment: Glad to hear it :) I don't really got what you want to do with the email function. But I guess that it should be possible to implement it in a WordPress. However it's not easy to do and requires specific WordPress development

Comment: Hi, the codes will be on the page (front end admin dashboard), not in the template or css or something.the process is like this: user fills in the field and send it by clicking the button. The email will have these information filled by the user.

Because the form is actually meant as a order form. Hence the need for the email function.

Comment: So this form is like a contact form ? If it is, I think you can use Ninja Form WordPress plugin [here](https://ninjaforms.com)  and create you're form with it. Then build your script with the Ninja form's data. I think this would work !

Comment: Actually, I would prefer to use free plugin. As far as I know, Ninja Form is not free right? And would the plugin have these functions as shown above which I had been pulling hair for past few hours?

Comment: The plugin is free for a basic usage. In your case, I think this is enough. The functions you already builds are not useless don't worries, you just have to generate the form with the plugin and adapt your script to this Ninja form generated form.

Comment: then how to add the script to the form? is it complicated? I am also new to CMS too. I am still learning.

Comment: First create the form with the plugin (you can create the same with it) and then adapt the script to the dom elements which will be created. But try Ninja form first, and you will see how it works

Comment: I have installed it and it seems to be similar to the code up there. But I cannot set the multiplication for the quantity of the clothes. I referred to the documentation but dont have info for this.

Comment: You can't set the field for the multiplication ?

Comment: Hi, after exploring with the plugin, I found the field. so sorry for the trouble. I will try it first tomorrow and let you know the result. if i have any issue, i will pm you. thanks and so sorry!

Comment: Let's do like that ! No problem, glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,
HTML

```
<form name="priceCalc" action="">Laundry (Gentlemen)
  <br/>Apparels:
  <select id="gapparell" />
    <option value="5.00">Tie</option>
    <option value="7.50">Shirt</option>
    <option value="12.50">Jacket</option>
  </select>
  <br>Quantity:
  <input type="text" id="gqtyl" />
  <br>
  <br/>Dry Cleaning (Gentlemen)
  <br/>Apparels:
  <select id="gappareld">
    <option value="6.00">Tie</option>
    <option value="8.50">Shirt</option>
    <option value="13.50">Jacket</option>
  </select>
  <br>Quantity:
  <input type="text" id="gqtyd" />
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>Laundry (Ladies)
  <br/>Apparels:
  <select id="lapparell" >
    <option value="5.00">Tie</option>
    <option value="7.50">Shirt</option>
    <option value="12.50">Jacket</option>
  </select>
  <br>Quantity:
  <input type="text" id="lqtyl"/>
  <br>
  <br/>Dry Cleaning (Ladies)
  <br/>Apparels:
  <select id="lappareld" onchange="ladiesd();">
    <option value="6.00">Tie</option>
    <option value="8.50">Shirt</option>
    <option value="13.50">Jacket</option>
  </select>
  <br>Quantity:
  <input type="text" id="lqtyd" onchange="ladiesd();" />
  <br>Total Cost:
  <input type="text" id="prices">
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="Figure out pricing!" onclick="total()">
  <br>
</form>
```

This is JS,

```
 function gentleman1() {
  var price=0;
  var e = document.getElementById('gapparell')
  var Amt = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var Qty = document.getElementById('gqtyl').value;
  price = parseInt(Qty) * parseFloat(Amt);
  return (isNaN(price)) ? 0 : price;
  //document.getElementById("prices").value = price;
}

function gentlemand() {
  var price=0;
  var e = document.getElementById('gappareld')
  var Amt = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var Qty = document.getElementById('gqtyd').value;
  price = parseInt(Qty) * parseFloat(Amt);
  return (isNaN(price)) ? 0 : price;
}

function ladies1() {
  var price=0;
  var e = document.getElementById('lapparell')
  var Amt = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var Qty = document.getElementById('lqtyl').value;
  price = parseInt(Qty) * parseFloat(Amt);
  return (isNaN(price)) ? 0 : price;
}

function ladiesd() {
  var price=0;
  var e = document.getElementById('lappareld')
  var Amt = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
  var Qty = document.getElementById('lqtyd').value;
  price = parseInt(Qty) * parseFloat(Amt);
  return (isNaN(price)) ? 0 : price;
}

function total() {
  var price=gentleman1()+gentlemand()+ladiesd()+ladiesd();
 document.getElementById('prices').value=price;

}
```

Working [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdzBMN?editors=101)